# Ubuntu 19.10 Dock keeps unwanted apps permanently. How can I remove them?

Tags: 19.10, ubuntu-dock

In Ubuntu 19.10, multiple corpses of apps remain in the dock after they are closed.  These are all apps opened from the terminal (display, ncview, etc).  However, not all instances of the opened application remain.  It looks random.  Restarting the computer doesn't get rid of them.  They are piling up now so any new app I open will be out of the screen and I need to scroll on the dock to reach it, which is really annoying.
A screenshot of the dock is attached.
Any solution?

[Image of the dock with multiple icon-less apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOZaD.png)